# What could I do when I run my excel macro and error 5487 (file permission error) appears?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have coded a marco in my excel. The macro could read data from the excel file and fill the data in an word template file. Each row of data will produce one word file.

There is an error 5487 when I run the code.
The following are my codes. Hope someone could point out what makes the error. Thanks very much.

```
Sub output()
    
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim savedFileName As String
    'Dim counter As Long

    
    
    
    'On Error GoTo CLOSEWORD
    
    'press the button
    msg = MsgBox("Be about to fill in data. Don't do anything!" & Chr(13) & "run or not？", _
    vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "confirm?")
    If msg = 7 Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'check if there is the template
    fileAddress = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template.doc")
    If fileAddress = "" Then
    msg = MsgBox("templete doesn't exist！", vbCritical, "WRONG")
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'do the job
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & fileAddress)
    

    For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

        'tempI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(3, 2) = "$" & moneyChange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5) * 100000000)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(4, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4)
              
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(4, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 11) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 12)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(5, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(6, 2) = "$" & moneyChange(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6))
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(7, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(8, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 9)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(9, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(9, 4) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 10)
        wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(12, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) 
    
        'save file
        savedFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) & ".doc"
        wordDoc.SaveAs (savedFileName)
        'counter = counter + 1
    
    Next i
    
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    
    wordDoc.Close
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    
    msg = MsgBox("complete", vbOKOnly, "Mission Complete")
        

    
End Sub
```

Comment: After line `savedFileName` add `MsgBox savedFileName` or `Debug.print savedFileName`. Check carefuly if the name is valid before `SaveAs` method. Remove curly brackets too.

Comment: You seem to be having problems spelling English words. "marco" and "templete" for example. So maybe there are simply typos in your code, variable names or strings that you use. In code, these details matter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rafał B.
the savedFileName contains some special char which makes the macro down.